# What is the opposite of interference, as in "radio interference"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

You might say, "This radio signal has a lot of interference".

If it gets better, you might say, "This radio signal has a high _______"?

Comment: What is the opposite of "murder"?

Comment: @HotLicks: *Rejuvenate*?

Comment: @jxh - That's "make young again".

Comment: The opposite of murder is necromancy.

Comment: @HotLicks the opposite of murder is: guard, preserve, protect, save

Comment: @3kstc - I didn't murder you (yet).  How did I do any of those things?

Comment: @HotLicks opposite meaning does not require reversal of effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say the signal is *clear*.

You might have heard the phrase "reading you loud and clear". This actually conveys two pieces of information. The signal is *loud* because you are receiving a strong signal. The signal is *clear* because there are no disturbances such as interference making the signal difficult to understand.

Comment: Since *interference* is a noun and the OP's example sentence also seems to call for a noun, you might want to include the noun form *clarity* in your answer.

Comment: @1006a, I'd say "the radio signal is clear" rather than use a noun form. Sometimes you have to switch between nouns and adjectives to get the most straightforward sentence.

Comment: You don't have to recommend it—you can specifically recommend *against* it—but it would still be worthwhile to mention it just in case there's a good reason for the OP to prefer a noun, and so it doesn't look like you missed that aspect of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I really like @jxh 's answer, which he (for some reason) deleted, so here it is:

`coherence`

Comment: From a technical point of view, this is incorrect. Coherence refers to a property a signal has in relation to delayed versions of itself. Inteference (in the sense that causes poor radio reception) is caused by a different signal on the same frequency.

Comment: Fair enough. This answer best suits my purposes, but the other one is more generally correct, so I'll select it as the answer.